# use setInterval() with a variable as ms value

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval

At component's initialization, I have a value coming from ngrx store that I'm using as a config

```
this.storeService.selectMConfig().subscribe(res => {
            if (!res) return;
            const refreshValue = Number(res.items[0].value) * 1000;
            this.intervalValue = refreshValue ?? 10000;
        });
```

I want to take this value and pass it in the setInterval function.

For the first version, the data is fetched every 10 seconds, but I want to parametrize it.

in the 2nd version, I am using `this.intervalValue` which is a number with value 10000.
Here, it enters an infinite loop and I don't know why or how to fix it
Why isn't it working with a variable?

```
        //v1
        setInterval(() => {
            this.storeService.fetchData(this.payload);
        }, 10000);

        //v2
        setInterval(() => {
            this.storeService.fetchPnrDashboardDetailsForMap(this.mapDetailsPayload);
            console.log('settimeout', this.mapRefreshConfig); // this.mapRefreshConfig = 10000
        }, this.mapRefreshConfig);
```

Comment: Are you confusing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`? `setInterval` sets a repeating interval that happens every (aproxximately) interval miliseconds but `setTimeout` just fires once after the specified time

Comment: No, I want a repeating interval

Comment: That seems to be at odds with your statement _"Here, it enters an infinite loop and I don't know why or how to fix it"_ You might have to explain your problem a bit clearer

Comment: Yes, I didn't express myself correctly. I want the repeating interval to be the one from this.mapRefreshConfig. But the behavior is to call this every ms regardless of the value passed in the setInterval

Comment: the 2nd one is due to it receiving undefined and its setting it to 0. Hence the infinite execution too fast or is it the rendering too much?

Comment: @user2004 Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

There's a section called "The "this" problem"

Comment: As @innocent said, you're going to need to make sure that `this.mapRefreshConfig` has an appropriate value before the v2 call to `setInterval` there's no way to change the interval unless you change the code to use repeated `setTimeout`s

Answer (score 0):

just make a controls for that interval. so you can change the function or time whatever you want. and if you want to pass some variable you can do it inside the function. something like this:

```js
const int_ = {
        
    f_              : false,
    time_           : 1000,
    funtion_        : false,
    controls_       : function(ord, val){

        if( ord == 'start' ){
            int_.controls_('stop');
            int_.f_ = setInterval(int_.funtion_, int_.time_);
        }
        else if( ord == 'stop' ){
            clearInterval(int_.f_);
        }
        else if( ord == 'set_time' ){
            int_.time_ = val;
        }
        else if( ord == 'set_function' ){
            int_.funtion_ = val;
        }
    }
};

// just for testing -----------------------------------

// try #1
int_.controls_('set_time', 1000);
int_.controls_('set_function', function(){
    console.log('hello');
});
int_.controls_('start');

// change the parameter in 5sec
// try #2
setTimeout(function(){
    
    int_.controls_('set_time', 5000);
    int_.controls_('set_function', function(){
        console.log('hello world');
    });
    int_.controls_('start');
}, 5000);
```